# Stripe API "No valid payment method types for this Payment Intent."

Tags: express, stripe-payments, backend

As you can imagine I'm currently setting up the payment API with using Stripe.
Problem is, I've never done such thing before and am following the docs pretty much one by one.

So I require stripe using (100% the right!) key.

```
const stripe = require("stripe")(
  "keyhere"
);
```

create the intent in a method...

```
const paymentIntent = stripe.paymentIntents.create({
  amount: process.env.AUDIT_PRICE,
  currency: "eur",
  automatic_payment_methods: { enabled: true },
});
```

call that method on a certain express route:

```
exports.createNewCashOrder = async (req, res) => {
  const intent = await paymentIntent();
  res.json({ client_secret: intent.client_secret });
};
```

The rest is irrelevant for now, since my backend server doesn't even start on localhost.
Actually it's live for like 0.001 seconds and than crashes with this error:

> StripeInvalidRequestError: No valid payment method types for this
> Payment Intent. Please ensure that you have activated payment methods
> compatible with your chosen currency in your dashboard

It also sends back a large error object, where at the end it says that pretty much everything (also the payment methods) are undefined.

[image: error]

Now on my dashboard, I did activate card payment, but it obviously somehow does not recognize it...

Any ideas what I've done wrong?
Glad for any help!

Answer (score 54, accepted):

This is just a hunch but is your amount too small?
https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents/create#create_payment_intent-amount

If that is the case you get this error because you specified

```
automatic_payment_methods: {enabled: true}
```

Stripe is looking for a payment method that can handle an amount lower than the minimum so that's why you get this error. Try specifying a payment method and see if you get a different error message that indicates the amount is too low.

Remember the docs state the amount is represented as

> A positive integer representing how much to charge in the smallest currency unit (e.g., 100 cents to charge $1.00 or 100 to charge ¥100, a zero-decimal currency).

### Update

As of the Stripe API version [2023-08-16](https://stripe.com/docs/upgrades#2023-08-16) `automatic_payment_methods` are enabled by default.  This means you may hit this error without specifying `automatic_payment_methods` in your request to the Payment Intent API if you are on the latest version.

Comment: That was it, interesting error log right there haha. Thank you!

Comment: This was also the issue for me! Thank you.

Comment: My case is the test numbers were too high.

Comment: In my case my test amount was too low

Comment: @Islam was right. I double checked the Stripe API documentation and it said amount is "A positive integer representing how much to charge *in the smallest currency unit* (e.g., 100 cents to charge $1.00 or 100 to charge ¥100, a zero-decimal currency). The minimum amount is $0.50 US or equivalent in charge currency."